# ¿Cómo puedo formatear un caracter utf-8 en python para guardarlo en un txt?

Tags: python

Trato de guardar una serie de ejercicios donde está el símbolo `√`, sin embargo al momento de guardarlo en un txt me arroja el siguiente error:
`SyntaxError: invalid character '√' (U+221A)`

El códgio que utilizo:

```
archivo = open(r'C:\Users\youna\Desktop\Ejercicio8.6.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

    fmts = {

      '√{} + √{} + √{}' : 'sqrt({}) + sqrt({}) + sqrt({})'

        }
    archivo.write(f'{view_expr}\n')
```

Tengo la versión de `Python 3.9.0`
No hay mucho que agregar, pero no logro darle solución a este problema. Si alguien me pudiera echar una mano le agradecería.

De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: escribe en el archivo esto: `f'{view_expr}\n'.encode('utf-8').decode()`

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: Por cierto, es recomendable que escribas una respuesta, así la pregunta no queda en el aire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si alguien tuviese en algún momento el problema de codificar el símbolo `√` u otro tipo de símbolo `utf-8`, lo que tienen que hacer es añadir a la variable la codificación `utf-8` como lo comentó @Christian:

```
archivo = open(r'C:\Tu_ruta\Archivo.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
variable = '√'
archivo.write(variabe.encode('utf-8').decode())
archivo.close()
```